# Where default email template like forget password,reset password,new account create etc. is stored in Magento 2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates

Where default email template  like forget password,reset password,new account create etc. is stored in Magento 2.1.12.What is path?

Answer (score 0):

Those email templates are stored at below path by default Magento

> magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/

And If your theme has over-written those, then they will be at path

> magentoRoot/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Customer/email/

Comment: when i will change in magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password-new.phtml ,this is not reflect in email template.

Comment: Check email template congratulations, set default or custom email template

Comment: Also when you change in HTML file, it required to run setup:upgrade and static:content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

All email templates are under below path

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email
```

Comment: when i will change in magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/email/password-new.phtml ,this is not reflect in email template.